# How to print to PDF completely silently and save the PDF to a predefined location in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, pdf, printing, printer

I'm trying to print to PDF completely silently and save the PDF to a predefined location in Mozilla Firefox. I don't want to interact with any GUI, I want to be able to just press `CTRL+P` or click on `Hamburger > Print` to print to PDF to the predefined location. I already tried setting the following options in `about:profile`, but it didn't work.

```
services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting: False
pdfjs.disabled: True
print.always_print_silent: True
print.show_print_progress: False
browser.download.show_plugins_in_list: False

browser.download.folderList: 2
browser.download.dir: (empty)
browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting: False
browser.aboutConfig.showWarning: False

print.print_headerright: (empty)
print.print_headercenter: (empty)
print.print_headerleft: (empty)
print.print_footerright: (empty)
print.print_footercenter: (empty)
print.print_footerleft: (empty)
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk: application/octet-stream;application/vnd.ms-excel;text/html

print.printer: Print to File
print.printer_Print_to_File.print_to_file: True
print.printer_Print_to_File.print_to_filename: /tmp/test.pdf
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to use some firefox extension that does the page to pdf conversion. That way you could get the PDF downloaded to your default downloading folder. If you are looking to set some folder other than default downloads folder then it could be very hard if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, if you give your PDF writer a nominated file as its Port, a simple `Ctrl-P Enter` will print to that file. Of course the GUI will pop up until you press `Enter`

And, the PDF printer has to be the default printer.